# Regex search function

Tags: python, regex

I was wondering lately if I can use any of the Regex function to find some word in another, for example:
word = "BCDAABCDBBDABB"
and now in this word i have to find word which starts with "AA" and ends with "BB". Is it even possible?

I had been trying with:
word = "BCDAABCDBBDABB"
re.search("AA.*BB", word) and my result is proper only if there is only one "BB" in my word. If there are more it always takes the last "BB" the function can find.

Comment: Are you trying to find all possible matches, or the shortest match?

Comment: You could try `non-greedy` way to find all matches.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this if you want only the part in the middle of AA and BB:***

```
(?<=AA).*?(?=BB)
```

***Or if this you want whole string, including AA and BB:***

```
AA.*?BB
```

Comment: Could you explain it with more details? I mean this one: (?<=AA).*?(?=BB)

Comment: The **(?<=AA)** part is a positive lookbehind, that will capture a string only if AA is in front of it, **(?=BB)** is a positive lookahead that will capture a string if BB is behind it, combining this two, the captured string will be what is in the middle of the two parts, which is what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

@malwina, "*Is it even possible?*" Yes: `re.search("AA.*?BB", word)`.
Consider this:

```
import re
text = "BCDAABCDBBDABB"

regex = r"AA.*BB"
print(re.search(regex, text).group(0))
# AABCDBBDABB

regex = r"AA.*?BB"
print(re.search(regex, text).group(0))
# AABCDBB

regex = r"(?<=AA).*(?=BB)"
print(re.search(regex, text).group(0))
# BCDBBDA

regex = r"(?<=AA).*?(?=BB)"
print(re.search(regex, text).group(0))
# BCD

regex = r"AA(.*)BB"
print(re.search(regex, text).group(0))
# AABCDBBDABB
print(re.search(regex, text).group(1))
# BCDBBDA

regex = r"AA(.*?)BB"
print(re.search(regex, text).group(0))
# AABCDBB
print(re.search(regex, text).group(1))
# BCD
```

`.*?` is *non-greedy* or *minimal* fashion.

Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html :

> `*?, +?, ??`
>
> The '*', '+', and '?' quantifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE <.*> is matched against '<a> b <c>', it will match the entire string, and not just '<a>'. Adding ? after the quantifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using the RE <.*?> will match only '<a>'.

Also look for "ungreedy" and "?U" in https://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt (note: `re.U` in Python means *Unicode matching* as `re.Unicode`, not *ungreedy*)

`(?=` and `(?<=` - look for "*lookahead* and *lookbehind*" assertions on the page above and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-21).